# String Processing On Server Or Android phone. Which is better?

Tags: php, android, server

I am working on an android application that uploads a file to my server and then gets a string response. The String requires modification before presenting to the user.Should the modification be done on the server or the phone...Which is faster?

Comment: You will answer that by yourself if you ask yourself... how much would that load my server?

Comment: Why not try both and see which is faster? I imagine local processing would be better, but for small sizes only.

Answer (score 1):

Server is something you control. If it's slow, upgrade it. But you cannot control devices and there are plethora of them, some are high-end some are low-end. 
So basically you cannot expect any processing to be fast on the device side because their performance is not uniform.

Having said that, I would suggest moving as much processing as possible to server side. A good app is light but rich. Just like Google. It's just a text field on client but behind the screen it is powered by thousands of servers.